# Run Tor proxy before a VPN

Tags: proxy, iptables, tor

I heard people say that running Tor's proxy before using a proxy is safer.
 How do that accomplish that? Would it be running proxychains with Tor's proxy on top of the list with other proxies?

Would it be proxify to tunnel all TCP traffic though TOR and use again proxychain but only with the vpn on it? Would it be with a IP TABLE chain?